# mongoose distinct and populate with documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model:

```
var followerSchema = new Schema({
    id_follower: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'},
    id_post: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Posts'}
});
```

I want to be able to find all posts for a list of followers. When I use find, it returns me of course multiple times the same post as multiple users can follow the same post.

So I tried to use distinct, but I have the feeling the "populate" does not work afterwards.

Here is my code:

```
followerModel
    .distinct('id_post',{id_follower:{$in:followerIds}})
    .populate('id_post')
    .sort({'id_post.creationDate':1})
    .exec(function (err, postFollowers) {
        console.log(postFollowers);
    })
```

It only returns me the array of the posts, and it is not populated.

I am new to mongoDB, but according to the documentation of mongoose, the "distinct" method should return a query, just as the "find" method. And on a query you can execute the "populate" method, so I don't see what I am doing wrong.

I also tried to use the .distinct() method of the query, so then my code was like this:

```
followerModel
    .find({id_follower:{$in:followerIds}})
    .populate('id_post')
    .distinct('id_post')
    .sort({'id_post.creationDate':1})
    .exec(function (err, postFollowers) {
        console.log(postFollowers);
    })
```

In that case it works, but as in the documentation of mongoose you need to provide a callback function when you use the distinct method on a query, and so in my logs I get errors all over. A workaround would be to have a dummy callback function, but I want to avoid that...

Does anybody has an idea why the first attempt is not working? And if the second approach is acceptable by providing a dummy callback?

Comment: It would appear it's not supported: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1549

Comment: You seem to be right, distinct send back an array of values, not the object you request (oid). But that is (in my opinion) not well documented, as the "distinct" method claims to return a query object, just as the "find" object.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7):

Would this be the right way considering the current lack of support in mongoose?

```
followerModel
.find({id_follower:{$in:followerIds}})
.distinct('id_post',function(error,ids) {
   Posts.find({'_id':{$in : ids}},function(err,result) {
     console.log(result);
   });
});
```

Comment: That is how I believe i would do it also.

Comment: but it's not really scalable is it? `Posts` is huge and a `currentUser` only needs a tiny percentage of them, all of which are stored through `id_follower.id_post`

Comment: @cubefox since it's filtered on Ids ```Posts.find({'_id':{$in : ids}}``` collection size is not an issue anymore. It scales even millions of records.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use aggregate to group and populate the collection.
now we have the desired result

```
db.<your collection name>.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {<match your fields here>}
  },
  {
    $group: {_id: <your field to group the collection>}
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
              from: "<your collection of the poupulated field  or referenced field>",
              localField: "<give the id of the field which yout want to populate from the collection you matched above cases>",
              foreignField: "_id", //this references the id of the document to match the localField id in the from collection
              
              as: 'arrayName', //<some name to the returned document, this is a single document array>
            }
  },
  {
    $project: {
     //you really don't want the whole populated fields, you can select the fields you want
     <field name>: 
<1 or 0>, // 1 to select and 0 to not select 
     //you can add multiple fields here 
     //to select the fields that just returned from the last stage we can use
     "arrayName._id": <1 or 0>,
      }
  }
])
//at last you can return the data
.then((data) =>{
  console.log(data);
});
```

we have `distinct()` by `$group` and
`populate()` by `$lookup`
and we also `select()` by `$project`