# mongoose extract nested arrays from multiple objects into one array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }],
    following: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }]
  }
};
```

I want to extract all the posts from all the Users in the `'following'` array, put them into one single array, sort them and then display the first 20. I was wondering if that is possible within the cursor or if I have to load it into memory.

```
function createFeed(user) {
  User.findOne({ name: user })
    .populate({
      path: "following",
      populate: {
        path: "posts"
      }
    })
//put all the posts into one array
.sort(...)  //sort by time created
.limit(...) //only get the newest n posts
.exec((err, result) => {
      if (err) console.log("error", err);
      console.log("result", //sorted tweets array);
 });
};
```

(I don't want to filter all the posts in my 'Posts' collection to check if they are made by the user since that would be a lot more expensive)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct` query in mongoDB

```
db.User.distinct('following',{})
```

Comment: thanks, seems like I can't use it with `.populate` though which means in the end I'm stuck using `.find()` again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077750/mongoose-distinct-and-populate-with-documents for refference

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter your populate with a condition, then you should be doing this:

```
User.findOne({ name: user })
.populate({
    path: 'posts',
    match: { user: 'XXX' }
})
```

Even more better would be to query the posts with the user filter condition and then populate user details.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, I don't really see how `match()` solves my problem. I need to filter my `Post` db for posts that were created by a person that my current user follows. A naive approach would be to just use something like `.find({post.creator: {in: currentUser. followers}})`  but if I do that then I have to filter through my entire 'posts' db, which is huge. If I only want to see the posts of people that my current user is following I can access them directly through user.following.posts. But I also want to sort them without loading all of them into memory...

Comment: how about use an aggregate query with a $filter. Its just a hint. You could try.